# javascript thymeleaf triggering a url

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf application that should do the following.

Persist some data to the database when the user clicks the submit button.  That same submit button must fetch some data from another server that has its own database; different from mine.  Here is my code (obviously, I am doing something wrong ergo my question here.)

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/index}" th:object="${notification}" class="contact-form">

        <div id="asset-search" class="row">
            <div class="col span-12-of-12">
                <!--                <div class="alert alert-info" th:if="${notificationSent}">Your feedback is greatly appreciated.-->
                <!--                </div>-->
            </div>
            <div class="col span-1-of-1">
                <label class="search-lbl">Tell us what you are searching for and we will try to find it. &nbsp;Please
                    include email if you wish us to contact you.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col span-2-of-2"> 
                <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" placeholder="Search" th:field="*{search}"> 
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email (Optional)" th:field="*{email}">
 
                <button type="submit"
                        th:data-url
                                ="@{http://auction.mainauctionservices.com/cgi-bin/mmcal.cgi?mainauction/keyword/{search}(search=${search}))}"
                        onclick="window.open(this.getAttribute('data-url'))">Go
                </button> 

                <!--<button type="submit" onclick="equipmentSearchFn()">Search</button>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

My controller is working fine.  It persists data.  No need to worry about the back end.  Maybe the controller could be rewritten, but its persisting.

HOWEVER, I need to fetch data from the back end of ANOTHER server.  The server that I need to get data from has the following format

"http://auction.mainauctionservices.com/cgi-bin/mmcal.cgi?mainauction/keyword/oven"  <--- the word oven comes from this input ... you can click the link you will see it will work; you can replace oven for table or sink and it will work.. that is the back end I am fetching from.

However the words oven or sink or table that the user types in the input search bar below are coming from this  th:field="*{search}

`<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" placeholder="Search" th:field="*{search}">`

It does not come from my database, it doesn't have to; it comes from what the user types in the search bar.

I tried to use the

```
                        th:data-url
                                ="@{http://auction.mainauctionservices.com/cgi-bin/mmcal.cgi?mainauction/keyword/{search}(search=${search}))}"
                        onclick="window.open(this.getAttribute('data-url'))">Go
                </button>
```

That you see up there but I don't know how to grab the search the user enters from the

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" placeholder="Search" th:field="*{search}">
```

My controller is this

```
public class IndexController {

@GetMapping({"", "index", "home"})
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("notification", new Notification());
        return "index";
    }

 
 
 @PostMapping(value = "/index")
    public void searchNotification(@Valid @ModelAttribute("notification") Notification notification,
                                     @RequestParam("search") String search,
                                     @RequestParam("email") String email,
                                     Model model, BindingResult result,
                                     HttpServletRequest request) {

       if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "index";
       }

        notification.setSearch(search);
        notification.setEmail(email);
        model.addAttribute("notification", notification);
        notificationService.save(notification);
        String appUrl = "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath() + "/";
        SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = mailConstructor.sendSearchNotification(appUrl, request.getLocale(), notification);
        javaMailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
        model.addAttribute("notificationSent", "true");
        model.addAttribute("appUrl", appUrl);
      return appUrl;
    }
}
```

I also tried using javascript which was my original thought but the javascript and the controller with return "index" were interfering with each other.

So, I tried to do it with what you see above

here is my javascript

```
function equipmentSearchFn() {
    let keyword; 
    let url;

    keyword = document.getElementById("keyword").value;
    url = "http://auction.mainauctionservices.com/cgi-bin/mmcal.cgi?mainauction/keyword/" + keyword;
    window.location = url;
}
```

ideally the javascript would be the fastest and best route but the problem is when its persisting the data via the controller im running into problems with a http POST trying to open a new page with the results..

i don't know if i am overworking this but its definitely got me overworked

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you want to have the browser redirect to an external URL after the POST to your controller. To do that, just return a `String` from your `searchNotification` method:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/index")
public void searchNotification(...) {
  
  ...

  String url = "http://auction.mainauctionservices.com/cgi-bin/mmcal.cgi?mainauction/keyword/" + search;
  return "redirect:" + url;
}
```

Comment: well that was simple enough.. i acutally laughed when i implemented your fix... it reminded me of the design principle KISS .. Keep It Simple Stupid.  Thanks for the help